# Cypress doesn't select the desired option from Select element in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, automation, cypress

In my automation testing project I need to select option from a select element.
I'm doing this with cypress and it's Angular project

I'm new to cypress and I did exactly what the documentation states

**Here's my select with cypress**

```
cy.get("#myElement").select(myOptionValue)
```

**Here's the html**

[image]

it didn't work.
is there any workaround or any way I can do it. *I didn't found any solution online*

*side note: when I run the test it looks like it selects it and then it returns back to the default one. maybe this is an issue with the angular code?*

Answer (score 0):

you are right according to [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Syntax)

try this `cy.get("#businesActivity").select('Service')`

Comment: yes, this is what I did. 
I just posted the statement like this to make it more generic so people here understand what I want to do

Comment: try this combination
first
`cy.get("#businesActivity").click();`
//then, when 'drop down' list will appeared
click on one of the option
`cy.contains("Traiding").click();`

Comment: tried it already. but select statement in cypress is not clickable!

Comment: Can you try one more assertion `cy.contains("Traiding").should('be.visible')` to understand if the select state is visible, and let me know

Comment: Yes it's visible

Comment: it is good already, we just need to click on it
`cy.contains("Traiding").should('be.visible').click()`
if needed use wait/sleep in between